# Regex with curly brackets

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex

I have following string:

```
{{blabla}}{{blabla}}xyzxyz{{blabla}}
```

What is proper regex match pattern to separate content in curly brackets and put it in the array?
I am working with RegExKitLite and Objective-C. I will very appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I have just solved this issue. Correct match pattern is `NSString *regex = "\\{\\{.*?\\}\\}";`

Answer (score 2):

`{{.*?}}` will match all content in double curly brackets.

Comment: Is ReqExLite greedy?  Because, if it is, it'll give you `blabla}}{{blabla}}xyzxyz{{blabla`

Comment: @Kirill Polishchuk, I also thought so until today. My code looks like: `NSString *regex = @"{{.*?}}; NSArray match = [stringToParse componentsSeparatedByRegex:regex];`. Array Match is nil all the way.